# Smooth scrolling to specific section on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

I am relatively new to coding and so there could be something super obvious that I am missing... but I am trying to create a button to scrolls to a specified section on my webpage. I have used an almost identical code on a previous webpage and it has worked beautifully, but for some reason I am struggling on this one and it just doesn't want to work no matter what I do!

Here is a simplified version of what I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".js--scroll-to-collection").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".js--section-collection").offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('.js--scroll-to-start').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.js--section-features').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div>
    <a class="btn js--scroll-to-collection" href="#">Shop</a>
    <a class="btn js--scroll-to-start" href="#">Shop</a>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section-features js--section-features">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>These are the features</h2>
    <p>
      This paragraph describes the features of the products on thi webpage.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="section-collection js--section-collection">
  <div>
    <h2>Meet the Collection</h2>
    <p>This section describes the different collections in the product range.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any help at all is really apreciated!

Comment: `$('html. body')` should have a comma as separator instead of a dot. In the collection click event handler.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed that but it still doesn't seem to be working?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fill the sections more than one page. here is the example with your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/y3dvtpf2/

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".js--scroll-to-collection").click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".js--section-collection").offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });

        $('.js--scroll-to-start').click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.js--section-features').offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });

    });
</script>
<section>
    <div>
        <a class="btn js--scroll-to-collection" href="#">Shop</a>
        <a class="btn js--scroll-to-start" href="#">Shop</a>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="section-features js--section-features">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>These are the features</h2>
        <p>
            This paragraph describes thedddd
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            features of the products on thi webpage.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="section-collection js--section-collection">
    <div>
        <h2>Meet the Collection</h2>
        <p>This section describes the different
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

            collections in the product range.</p>
    </div>
</section>

</html>
```

Comment: hi thank you so much. I am still so confused because when I run this on the link you have posted or on codepen it works. However, when I copy and paste the exact code into the code I am working on, it does not work. Any suggestion sas to why this happens?!

Comment: do you use more libraries in your code? i guess one of them blocks your clicks. do you know how to use breakpoints?

Comment: Hi I don't think I use any more libraries. Do you mean breakpoints as in screen width pixel breakpoints? I was about to write in some jquery for responsive page layout but I have not yet